# Designing database for ACL

Tags: php, database, database-design, orm, acl

For the project I'm working on, I need to design a database for users, items of several different types, and acl-like permission system.

Basically, this is what I wanted to do (much more complex, but this is enough to demonstrate what I mean):

- user: (id, name, password)
- article: (id, title, body)
- image: (id, title, file_name)
- permission: (item_type, item_id, user_id, read, write, manage)

(itemType and itemId are together a composite foreign key, referencing article or image, depending on item_type)

Some would say using a permission table is not a good idea, and that same can be achieved by adding read, write and manage columns to article and image, but keep in mind that there might be multiple users with different rights to same items. It's not an option to give that up.

In my opinion, this would work fine. But when it comes to implementation, I couldn't find a single php orm to give me some freedom to do this. This lead me to believe I might be doing something wrong.

So, my questions are:
What is the correct way to implement an ACL and design database for that?
How is it done for enterprise level applications?
Are there any non-db ACL solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to have one `many-to-many` table which will bind users to permissions and probably objects that will solve your choking point. 
It will have - user_id and permission_id and object_id will be referencing 3 different tables.

Means will be something like:

```
user_id(references users),permission_id(references permissions),object_id (references image?)
1 ,2(read),2
1 ,3(write),2
1 , 4(exec),2
```

---

hope it helps abit